# Posting a form with optional and mandatory fields

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add to my database information from a form if I have mandatory and optional fields? So far I have only done a few inserts but in all of those all the information was always present. In this case I am making a contact form where the name, surname and cellphone number are mandatory and where all the others are optional.

Also the person's information (name, surnames, nickname) goes into a table while the numbers (home, work, fax, cell etc) goes into another table.

A example (of another app) code I have used for POST:

**jQuery (Ajax)**

```
$("#btnAceptar").click(function() {
  var codigolab = $('#txtNumLab').val(),
  capacidad = $('#txtCapacidad').val(),
  carrera = $('#txtCarrera').val(),
  ubicacion = $('#txtUbicacion').val();


var request = $.ajax({
url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
type: "post",
data: {

    'call': 'addLab',
    'pCodigoLab':codigolab,
    'pCapacidad':capacidad,
    'pCarrera':carrera,
    'pUbicacion':ubicacion},

    dataType: 'html',

   success: function(response){
    $('#info').html(response);


     }
  });
});
```

**PHP I use in this example to add to the database**

```
function addLab(){     
if(isset($_POST['pCodigoLab']) && 
    isset($_POST['pCapacidad']) &&
    isset($_POST['pCarrera']) &&
    isset ($_POST['pUbicacion'])){

    $codigolab = $_POST['pCodigoLab'];
    $capacidad = $_POST['pCapacidad'];
    $carrera = $_POST['pCarrera'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['pUbicacion'];


    $query = "INSERT INTO labs VALUES" . "('null', '$codigolab', '$capacidad', '$carrera','$ubicacion', '1')";

    $result = do_query($query);

    echo "<p>¡El laboratorio ha sido añadido exitosamente!</p>";


}
```

}

In this case where I am making some fields mandatory and others not I need to insert into different tables, to add another insert into that query do I just use a AND or something like that?

Also if the user doesn't input anything in some fields do I leave the optional fields out of the isset statements? How would those variables be declared if I cannot be certain if they're going to be used?

Sorry if I am making this a bit hard to follow I am a bit confused and english is not my main language.

Thanks in advance.

FIDDLE OF the actual code:

[Pressing Guardar button displays the fields that are mandatory the others are optional.](http://jsfiddle.net/AsBT7/)

Thanks

Comment: i guess you need to make up your mind abt those you can do isset for mandatory fields and !empty for optional fields for further use :)

Comment: @M.chaudhry I thought was much I was just not sure if the syntax was correct or even frowned upon. But do you know how can I send INSERTS into two different tables i one query>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have the fields `name`, `email`, `note` where the first 2 are required and the last one is not.

Here is one way to do it:

```
<?php
$error = array();
if (!isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $error[] = "The field name was not filled!";
}

if (!isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $error[] = "The field email was not filled!";
}

if (sizeof($error) == 0)
{
    // insert the data
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
                     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
                     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),
                     mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_POST['note']) ? $_POST['note'] : '')));

    $result = do_query($query);
    echo "<p>¡El laboratorio ha sido añadido exitosamente!</p>";
}
else
{
    // print the error
    foreach ($error as $msg)
    {
        echo $msg, "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

[**For `note` I used a ternary operator:**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
isset($_POST['note']) ? $_POST['note'] : ''
```

Which essentially is a one liner if/else, which could have been written as:

```
if (isset($_POST['note']))
{
    $note = $_POST['note'];
}
else
{
    $note = '';
}
```

Also make sure you sanitize your data in your case using `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will tinker around your example and try to do it on my own from here on unless I hit a brick wall and have to come with my metaphorical tail between my legs.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper one of the good points of doing it that way is that if an error occur you can return the array with the list of errors instead of printing it directly and use it on some other part of your code and of course you can improve it by checking if the email is actually an valid email or in your case what kinda of fields you have and if the user input it right.

Comment: I still have much to learn it seems. Thanks a lot for your help, I will resume my coding tomorrow because I am dead on my feet from fatigue right now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be (I'm not an expert at PHP, so others may have a better solution):

```
$codigolab = isset($_POST['pCodigoLab']) ? "'" . $_POST['pCodigoLab'] . "'" : NULL;
$capacidad = isset($_POST['pCapacidad']) ? "'" . $_POST['pCapacidad'] . "'" : NULL;
$carrera = isset($_POST['pCarrera']) ? "'" . $_POST['pCarrera'] . "'" : NULL;
$ubicacion = isset($_POST['pUbicacion']) ? "'" . $_POST['pUbicacion'] . "'" : NULL;
```

This would mean that you would need to remove the single quotes from your SQL.

One word of warning:  With your SQL, please look into prepared statements.  As is, it would be easy to send pUbicacion = "*-');DELETE labs;--*" (Or something similar.)  This would allow a person to use a SQL injection and either alter or delete your data.

Edit:  Add link to PHP's mysqli_prepare page: [PHP::mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thanks! It is for practicing purposes but so I have been told, I really need to find a roundabout way to that,,,