# Using PHP POST method to post to the same page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tried figuring this out on my own using previous threads, but other peoples' examples didn't quite help me figure out what I need. The stand-alone files themselves work, data gets inserted into the DB just fine... but I'm trying to adapt these documents a bit to work as an all-in-one, single PHP document.

I figure I'll just throw out what I'm trying to do and the code I have so far, and maybe someone will understand what I'm trying to accomplish and be able to explain how to do it.

I basically have an PHP document with form (form.php) that uses POST to send the form data to a second PHP document, which in turn sends the form data to a MySQL database. I want the user to be able to post the data using the same document and have the data fields reset so that the user and submit enter more information through the form. I would like the make the user aware of errors due to incomplete fields, and I would like the user to be made aware of successful entries (which I will do using the echo function).

form.php is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <title>MySQL Database Creation System</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="eris.png" align="middle">
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        Firstname: <input type="text" size="16" name="firstname">
        Lastname: <input type="text" size="16" name="lastname">
        Age: <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" name="age">
        <input type="submit" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

insert.php is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="insert.css">
    <title>MySQL Database Creation System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <img src='eris.png' align='middle'>
        <?php
        if ( (trim($_POST['firstname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['lastname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['age']) == "") )
        {
            echo "<p>ERROR: All fields must be completed</p>";
            echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
        }
        else
        {
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","my_db");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
              echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            // escape variables for security
            $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
            $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
            $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

            $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
            VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
              die('<br>Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }

            mysqli_close($con);

            echo "<p>New item added.</p>";
            echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give.

Comment: [See this answer it might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23166295/342740)

Comment: Don't use an `action` in your form if posting to self.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your `form.php` like below -

***What have I done here -***

1)  `<form action="insert.php" method="post">`
     
                                **TO**
 
         `<form action="" method="post">`

2) Added all of your `php code` in `form.php`

```
 <?php
    if ( (trim($_POST['firstname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['lastname']) == "") ||     (trim($_POST['age']) == "") )
    {
        echo "<p>ERROR: All fields must be completed</p>";
        echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
    }
    else
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","my_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
          echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // escape variables for security
        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

        $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
          die('<br>Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        mysqli_close($con);

        echo "<p>New item added.</p>";
        echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <title>MySQL Database Creation System</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="eris.png" align="middle">
    <form action="" method="post">
    Firstname: <input type="text" size="16" name="firstname">
    Lastname: <input type="text" size="16" name="lastname">
    Age: <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" name="age">
    <input type="submit" class="button">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get the point. In this case you are near. Just merge your scripts like this:

```
<?php
// check if there is a post request ...
// if not - nothing happens
if(!empty($_POST))
{
   if ( (trim($_POST['firstname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['lastname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['age']) == "") )
    {
        echo "<p>ERROR: All fields must be completed</p>";
        echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
    }
    else
    {
        // your inser code
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","my_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
          echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // escape variables for security
        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

        $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
          die('<br>Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        mysqli_close($con);

        echo "<p>New item added.</p>";
        echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <title>MySQL Database Creation System</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="eris.png" align="middle">
        <!-- change insert.php to form.php -->
        <form action="form.php" method="post">
            Firstname: <input type="text" size="16" name="firstname">
            Lastname: <input type="text" size="16" name="lastname">
            Age: <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" name="age">
        <input type="submit" class="button">
    </form>
</div>
```

I hope that is near your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Then Your form page should like this.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
        <title>MySQL Database Creation System</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="eris.png" align="middle">
            <form action="" method="post">
            Firstname: <input type="text" size="16" name="firstname">
            Lastname: <input type="text" size="16" name="lastname">
            Age: <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" name="age">
            <input type="submit" class="button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <?php
    if ( (trim($_POST['firstname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['lastname']) == "") || (trim($_POST['age']) == "") )
    {
        echo "<p>ERROR: All fields must be completed</p>";
        echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
    }
    else
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","my_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
          echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // escape variables for security
        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

        $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
          die('<br>Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        mysqli_close($con);

        echo "<p>New item added.</p>";
        echo "<p><a href='form.php'>Return to Form</a></p>";
    }
    ?>
```

Thanx